# How to bind checkboxes from custom form into SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using JavaScript to get all the checkboxes with the name "days", check which ones are checked and add their values into an Array.

HTML checkboxes look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Sunday"/>Sunday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Monday"/>Monday
```

My script that puts all the checked values into an Array looks like:

```
var arr = new Array();

$('input[name="days"]:checked').each(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
});

return arr;
```

When I hit "Submit" (I am using Forms7), it gets added to the SharePoint list fine.

However, when I try to edit that list item, all the checkboxes are unselected. For example, if I checked 'Sunday' upon creating a list item, it will not be checked when I edit it.

Any thoughts on how checkbox binding works in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. SharePoint uses `";#"` instead of `","` as a separator for array items.

For example, this is what happens behind-the-scenes if I check the checkboxes with the values ("one", "two", "three") and submit the list item:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push("one");
arr.push("two");
arr.push("three");
```

Normally, `arr.toString()` in JavaScript would result as:

```
one, two, three
```

But with SharePoint, this is what it recognizes:

```
one;#two;#three
```

So I had to use `arr.join(";#");` in order to replace the commas. When I edit the list item, checkboxes ("one", "two", "three") are still checked.

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend spservices http://spservices.codeplex.com/

1. add js library to virtual directory and put link into master page
2. attach sript to form, get list values
3. initialize check boxes, whenn document (form) is loaded